# Broken Image Link (Menu)

Tags: menu

I have a fresh install of CiviCRM. Some of the menus show a broken image file. Can this be removed?

[image: Menu]

Comment: Strange, it looks as if everything is in place and rebuilding the menus didn't work. I'm using Drupal. Take a look and let me know what you think. CiviCRM Resource URL: **//sites/all/modules/civicrm**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be a small arrow there:

[image: Admin menu]

If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say your "CiviCRM Resource URL" may not be set correctly. Check in **Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs**.

If that URL is correct, check to see if this file exists on your server:
`/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/css/images/arrow.png`

Comment: Seems like everything is in place, please check my comment below.

Comment: Actually, you were right. For some reason the was a double // added before sites. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If resource file is correct you can try to rebuild menus and don't forget to clear the civicrm cache.

Drupal sites: http:///index.php?q=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1

Joomla 1.5 sites: http:///administrator/index2.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1

Joomla 1.6 sites: http:///administrator/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1

Wordpress sites: http:///wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1