# Broken Navigation Image Gifs,and

Tags: menu, images

Thanks for assisting .. I have just a couple of questions:

1)  I'm a little puzzled by missing navigation icons (see below)..and it would appear to be using a relative reference. I'm hosting CiviCRM on the Google cloud thru Bitnami which is by and large working pretty well. Nowhere in the configuration would appear to allow me to put in specific reference of the IP where CiviCRM is hosted.  I can see the image gifs with the specific IP and image path.  Saw a post [Broken Image Link (Menu)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2961/broken-image-link-menu#new-answer?newreg=da74d0afa4a0403f85507a5f0cadceb1)  but didnt quite work for me.

[image]

2) In configuring the Navigation Menu, I could not remove the sub menu items of Events and other top menu items.  I was able to do so in a local install previously when I would simply click on the Events link, and all the sub menu items displayed below, and I simply deleted the sub menu items, click to refresh and it was done.  With this install on the cloud - there is no response when I click on Events menu item.  But I could right click on it do Rename, Delete and Edit the main menu item.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Base URL is set in `civicrm.settings.php`.  From your screenshot, it looks like you're running CiviCRM on Drupal; find `civicrm.settings.php` in `<drupal root>/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php`.